# Custom Post Type not showing in Rest API on Multisite

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, wp-api

I'm using WP Multisite and can't seem to pull through my custom post types via the API.

```
<?php
function terms_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Policies', 'Post Type General Name', 'name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Policy', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'name' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Policies', 'name' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Policy', 'name' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Policies', 'name' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Policy', 'name' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Policy', 'name' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'name' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Policy', 'name' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Policy', 'name' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Policy', 'name' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'name' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'name' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Policies', 'name' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Terms and Conditions', 'name' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'rest_base'           => 'policy',
        'show_in_rest'        => true
    );

    register_post_type( 'policy', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'terms_post_type', 1 );
```

When I then hit http://.localtest.me/wp-json/wp/v2/policy I get:

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

Feel like I'm overlooking something.

Comment: try adding a (mostly unnecessary) comma after the last true

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same issue @marvinpoo

Comment: Hmm, do other REST requests work?

Comment: Yeah all other requests work, when I call `http://<sitename>.localtest.me/wp-json` I see all standard endpoints only missing ones are the custom post types

Comment: have you added posts in the custom post type already? I tried to recreate that (even without comma) and it seemed to work with cpt's that have new posts. Otherwise you could try `'show_in_rest'          => true,
  'rest_base'             => 'base',
  'rest_controller_class' => 'controller',` and then check the /wp-json/wp/v2/ link for the endpoint. if that works, then you could try to reset it.

Comment: Think there's something in the theme tripping it out, I moved the CPT to a plugin and deactivated the theme and it works fine. When I find out what it is I'll post it back here.

Comment: fell free to come back again! I will answer back when I am in the office tomorrow, if noone else can help you. Cheers!